# OpenCV Ubuntu Installation Issues

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, installation

I have been working on OpenCV installation from the last 4 days but still can't find a way to install it without errors.

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
apps/visualisation/CMakeFiles/opencv_visualisation.dir/build.make:104: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_visualisation' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_visualisation] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7461: recipe for target 'apps/visualisation/CMakeFiles/opencv_visualisation.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [apps/visualisation/CMakeFiles/opencv_visualisation.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be too difficult:

```
# Get all the up-to-date tools you'll need
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git cmake build-essential

# Get latest greatest OpenCV from GitHub
cd
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git

# Go build and install that puppy
cd opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j 8 
sudo make install
```

Comment: @killbill Which step didn't work? What was the error message? It's very hard to help when we can't see what you have done...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try running the file from this [link](https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh). The good thing about this is that it abstracts so many things from you. You need not manually run all the commands. Run it on the ubuntu terminal as `bash install-opencv.sh`. 

Just let me know incase of any errors.